# Data Collector Set was not found (0x80300002) on Scheduled Task

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, scheduled-task, scom, sharepoint-2013, appfabric

Server: **Microsoft Windows 2012 R2 (w/ SharePoint 2013 on the system).**

Getting the this error:

```
Data Collector Set was not found (0x80300002)
```

I have a scheduled task that runs automatically on system restart. I am not sure if this is built-in, created by third-party software or created in-house.

**Scheduled Task in Task Scheduler**

[image: Scheduled Task in Task Scheduler]

We are getting the below alert on SCOM:

```
Job/Task StartFabricTraces Failed with exit code -2144337918 (0x80300002). Last run date was 10/19/2018 4:08:41 PM
```

I have tried to run the process manually but I am getting the data set collector error.

Upon some research I also checked in `Computer Management -> Performance -> Data Collector Sets` but could not find any Data Sets with the same name as the event/command.

The sheduled task is called `StartFabricTraces` and runs a .cmd called `StartTracing.cmd` located in `C:\Program Files\Windows Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code.1.0`.

The contents are as below:

```
@echo OFF

call logman start FabricTraces > NUL
call logman start FabricLeaseLayerTraces > NUL
```

Tried running the code manually into a Command Prompt and I get no output. When I remove the trailing `> NUL` I get the `Data Collector Set` was not found (0x80300002) error

[image: Error]

Any idea how I can run this scheduled task successfully and what it's use is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This scheduled task starts trace logging for windows fabric, which is installed as a [prerequisite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-0#software-requirements) for sharepoint 2013.  I would imagine that some part of the installer or application itself creates the data collector sets.  The reason you're not seeing the error when you run it from command prompt is because the output is redirected to NUL.  The error is still happening, it's just not being outputted to the console.  When it's run by the scheduled task the error is captured and reported as you're seeing.

IMO you have 2 options now...

Option 1: You can disable the scheduled task.  If you haven't had need for these log files yet then odds are you might not in the future.  I don't know exactly what's in these log files but the sysadmin in me says disabling it would be fine and you probably wouldn't need the information unless you had to troubleshoot something related to windows fabric.

Option 2: You can try to restore those data collector sets.  You could search the windows fabric directories to see if the .xml template files might be there.  If they are, start up performance monitor and create a new data collector set from template (browse to the appropriate .xml files) for each.  Alternatively, If you have any other boxes running similar software they might have those data collector sets and you can copy them over (save as a template and then create new from template on destination box).